# In Entity Framework, how can I use aggregate functions in the Select clause?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq

Is it possible to convert the following working SQL statement into an Entity Framework query?

```
SELECT Year([Model Date])
       ,Model
       ,COUNT(SERIAL) AS [Model Count]
       ,(SUM([SCORE])/COUNT(SERIAL)) as [Average SCORE]
       ,(COUNT(SERIAL)/SUM([SCORE])) * 100 AS [Score Rate]
FROM [MODELS]
WHERE Model IS NOT NULL 
AND [ACE PROFILE] <> 0
AND SERIAL IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Model, Year([Model Date])
```

Comment: Well did you try it first?

Comment: i did!  but i kept getting access errors in the select clause.  Looks like I jacked up my group somehow.  Weihan got me squared.  Thanks all.

Comment: You're supposed to share what you have tried, this isn't a code writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Db : DbContext
{
    public Db(string connection) : base(connection) {}
    public DbSet<MODEL> MODELS { get; set; }
}

[Table("MODELS")]
public class MODEL
{
    [Key]
    public string Model { get; set; }
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Column("ACE PROFILE")]
    public int? ACE_PROFILE { get; set; }
    public int? SERIAL { get; set; }
    public int? SCORE { get; set; }
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Column("Average SCORE")]
    public int Average_SCORE { get; set; }
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Column("Model Date")]
    public DateTime Model_Date { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    var db = new Db(Connection.ConnectionString);

    var result =    from T in db.MODELS
                    where T.Model != null && T.ACE_PROFILE != 0 && T.SERIAL != null
                    group T by new { DateYear = T.Model_Date.Year, T.Model } into g
                    select new
                    {
                        g.Key.DateYear,
                        g.Key.Model,
                        Model_Count = g.Count(c => c.SERIAL != null),
                        Average_SCORE = g.Sum(c => c.SCORE ) / g.Count(c => c.SERIAL != null),
                        Score_Rate = (g.Count(c => c.SERIAL != null) / g.Sum(c => c.SCORE)) * 100
                    };
}
```